# Unknown assembly with random name loaded by WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, assemblies

I have a WPF application and I notice that when I run it there's a line in Visual Studio's output window which says

> 'SomeApp.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'lwrpft7j'

The name is different every time. It is listed when I call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` as well.

What is this random assembly?

Comment: Normal WPF, as far as I know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the Xml serializer or acompiled Regex? Some framework classes dynamically generate and compile code and then load the resulting assembly.

Comment: I am using XML Serializer, so perhaps that's it.

Comment: You could try setting a breakpoint at the position where the XmlSerializer is used, to see if that line causes the load. If that doesn't help you could maybe hook up the AssemblyResolve event on your app domain and stick a breakpoint in the handler.